# How to manage a simple blog table structure with JPA and hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I want to define an entity of blog like this:

```
Blog{
 ...
 likeCount: Int
 commentCount: Int
}
```

I don't want to define likeCount as a field that exists in Blog table.
I want it to be calculated from the `BlogLike` table when I access the field.
After google for a while, I learned hibernate's `@Formula` annotation may be a choice.

And my main problem is about the BlogLike table, the structure is like this:

```
BlogLike{
 bid: Long
 uid: Long
}
```

`bid` is the id of the blog and `uid` is the id of the user

### now, my problem is , `how can I define the ForeignKey constraint?`

### or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying for a while,I found a way to do it

```kotlin
@Entity
@IdClass(BlogLike.BlogLikeId::class)
class BlogLike {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bid")
    lateinit var blog: Blog
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "uid")
    lateinit var user: User

   class BlogLikeId: Serializable {
       var blog: Long? = null
       var user: Long? = null
   }
}
```